# c++ Lista simplemente enlazada insertar ordenado

Tags: c++

Tengo una lista simplemente enlazada que está guardada en un archivo binario, lo que quiero es utilizar la función *insertarOrdenado* para que cada vez que agrego un nodo a la lista lo guarde en la posición que corresponda de acuerdo a un criterio, para que después cuando tenga que mostrar toda la lista, todos los elementos que fui guardando ya aparezcan ordenados.

El criterio seria que las pólizas estén ordenadas por cantidad de accidentes descendente. Por ejemplo si ingreso:

> *Poliza 0001, cant de accidentes **0***
>
> *Poliza 0002, cant de accidentes **3***

Cuando pida ver los elementos de la lista me tendría que aparecer así:

> *Poliza 0002, cant de accidentes **3***
>
> *Poliza 0001, cant de accidentes **0***

Justamente mi problema es que la funcion *insertarOrdenado* no me estaría funcionando, y en vez de guardar las polizas ordenadas me las muestra en el orden que las fui cargando.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ESTADO 'V'
#define ARCHIVOP "Asegurados.BAK"
using namespace std;

struct Poliza{ 
    char nro[4];
    int cantIncidentes = 0;
};

struct Nodo{
    Poliza dato;
    Nodo *siguiente;
};

void insertarOrdenado(Nodo* &inicioLista, int valor) // DESCENDENTE
{
    Nodo* actual = inicioLista;
    Nodo* aux;
    Nodo* nuevo;
    nuevo = new Nodo;
    nuevo->dato.cantIncidentes = valor;

    //Mientras el nodo actual no apunte al final de la lista (mientras me pueda mover en la lista)
    // y el dato del nodo actual sea mayor que el valor que quiero guardar
    //voy a pedirle a aux que apunte al nodo actual, y a actual le pido de apunte al siguiente nodo
    while (actual!=NULL && actual->dato.cantIncidentes>valor)
    {
        aux = actual;
        actual = actual->siguiente;
    }

    //CASO: INSERTO NODO AL PPIO (NO ENTRA AL WHILE!!!)
    //Si la lista está vacía, inicio y actual apuntan a NULL
    // Si la lista NO está vacía, inicio y actual apuntan al primer nodo que es distinto de NULL
    // de cualquiera de las dos formas inicio y actual APUNTAN A LO MISMO
    if (inicioLista == actual)
        inicioLista = nuevo;
    else    //CASO: INSERTO NODO EN MEDIO O AL FINAL
        aux->siguiente = nuevo;

    nuevo->siguiente = actual; //Luego de insertar el nuevo nodo, le pido que apunte al que le sigue que seria actual

    return;
}

Nodo* cargarPoliza (Nodo* inicio)
{
    Nodo* nuevo = new Nodo;   
    FILE *f;

    if ( !(f = fopen(ARCHIVOP, "ab+")) )
        cout << "NO SE PUDO ABRIR EL ARCHIVO." << endl;

    
    cout << "Ingrese Nro de poliza (XXXX): " ;
    cin >> nuevo->dato.nro;
    cout << "Ingrese cantidad de incidentes: ";
    cin >> nuevo -> dato.cantIncidentes;

    insertarOrdenado (inicio, nuevo->dato.cantIncidentes);

    if ( !(f = fopen(ARCHIVOP, "ab+")) )
    {
        cout << "NO SE PUDO ABRIR EL ARCHIVO." << endl;
    }

    for(Nodo *aux = inicio; aux; aux = aux->siguiente)
         fwrite(&nuevo->dato, sizeof(Nodo), 1, f);

    return inicio;
}

void listarPolizas(char rutanombre[]) 
{
    FILE *f;
    Poliza p;

    if (f = fopen(rutanombre, "rb"))
    {
        fread(&p, sizeof(Poliza), 1, f);
        while (!feof(f))    //itera mientras no llegue l final del archivo
        {
            cout <<"\n---------------------------------" << endl;
            cout << "   Nro. de poliza: " << p.nro << endl;
            cout << "   Cantidad de incidentes: " << p.cantIncidentes << endl;
            cout << "---------------------------------" << endl;
            fread(&p, sizeof(Poliza), 1, f);
        }
    }
    else
          cout << "NO SE PUDO ABRIR EL ARCHIVO." << endl;

    fclose(f);

    return;
}

void imprimir_lista(Nodo* inicioLista) {
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen(ARCHIVOP, "rb");

    for (Nodo* aux = inicioLista; aux != NULL; aux = aux->siguiente)
    {
        fread(&aux->dato, sizeof(Nodo), 1,  f);

        cout <<"\n---------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "   Nro. de poliza: " << aux->dato.nro << endl;
        cout << "   Cantidad de incidentes: " << aux->dato.cantIncidentes << endl;
        cout << "---------------------------------" << endl;
    }
    fclose(f);
    return;
}

void mostrarMenu ()
{
    cout << endl << "   ***MENU***  " << endl;
    cout << "1. Cargar nueva poliza. " << endl;
    cout << "2. Listar polizas." << endl;
    cout << "3. Salir" << endl;

    return;
}

int main ()
{
    char opcion;
    Nodo *lista = NULL;

    do
    {
        mostrarMenu();
        cin >> opcion;


        switch(opcion)
        {
            case '1':
                lista = cargarPoliza(lista);
                break;

            case '2':
                listarPolizas(ARCHIVOP);
                break;

            case '3':
                break;

        cout << "Presione una tecla para continuar." << endl;
        getch();


        }
    }while(opcion!='3');


    return 0;
}
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmiuD.png]

Comment: Si al intentar abrir un archivo para escritura te dice que no se puede abrir, muy posiblemente sea por no haberlo cerrado anteriormente. De hecho, en `cargarPoliza` veo dos `fopen` y ningún `fclose`. Es por eso que son mejores los flujos de datos, porque al seguir el principio RAII es más difícil olvidarse cerrarlos.

Answer (score 2):

Las escrituras en archivo son secuenciales (un dato se escribe después de otro) y no tienen relación alguna con cómo gestiones tus objetos en memoria.

Si quieres **reordenar** los datos de un archivo tienes dos opciones:

1. Volver a escribir el archivo al completo, con los datos ya ordenados.
2. Si todos tus registros tienen el mismo tamaño (que parece ser el caso) escribir en las posiciones del archivo en que los datos se reordenan.

La primera opción es la más sencilla:

```
Nodo* cargarPoliza (Nodo* inicio)
{
    // Puedes crear e inicializar en un solo paso.
    Nodo* nuevo = new Nodo;

    // Después de crear el nodo, ya puedes empezar a pedir datos.
    cout << "Ingrese Nro de poliza (XXXX): " ;
    cin >> nuevo->dato.nro;
    cout << "Ingrese cantidad de incidentes: ";
    cin >> nuevo -> dato.cantIncidentes;

    // Una vez leídos los datos, los guardamos para que
    // antes de escribir el archivo ya estén ordenados.
    insertarOrdenado (inicio, nuevo -> dato.cantIncidentes);

    // En C++ se usan los flujos de datos (stream) para leer y escribir información
    // La utilidad 'FILE' pertenece a C, no la uses.
    if (std::ostream f{ARCHIVOP})
    {
        // Escribimos TODOS los datos, en el orden en que están en memoria
        for (Nodo *n = inicio; n; n = n->siguiente)
            f.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&n->dato), sizeof(n->dato));
    }
    else
        // Si el archivo no se pudo abrir, iremos directamente al 'else'.
        cout << "NO SE PUDO ABRIR EL ARCHIVO.\n";

    // No se necesita 'close', el flujo de datos se cierra solo en su destructor.

    return inicio;
}
```

Comment: Holaa, gracias por ayudarme de nuevo!!  Entiendo lo que me decís de que no debería escribir así los archivos, La razón por la que los uso asi como si fuera C es porque así me lo piden en la facultad (supuestamente así es más fácil de aprender a usarlos), también por esa misma razón al final de cada cout uso un endl, aunque en otra pregunta que hice anteriormente me explicaste que con una llamada es suficiente. Modifiqué el código según tus observaciones pero ahora cuando quiero ver todas las polizas que guarde me aparece un nuevo problema que es el que adjunte en la imagen.

Comment: Di en tu facultad de mi parte, que están enseñando C++ en 2021 como si fuese 1996 y eso está mal.